# Use Recyclerview Adapter as an Adapter for Spinner

Tags: android

I am not familiar with `Recyclerview` and I want to use `Recyclerview` adapter as an adapter for spinner.

Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Spinner` cannot use a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. You need to use something that implements `SpinnerAdapter`, such as `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you, can I build like-spinner view using RecyclerView?

Comment: @MohanadRefaai: I do not know of any good way to do that, and the Android Arsenal does not appear to have a library for it. Sorry!